# How to use bip32 to generate a rsa keypair? Is it even possible?

Tags: rsa, blockchain, public-key-encryption, bitcoin, deterministic

I am trying to solve a multi device app problem using mnemonics and generating a bip32 keypair. But as far as I have read, there was no mention of public key encryption using these bip32 keypair, so is it possible to achieve public key encryption using this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through a lot of articles, websites, I didn't find anything helpful. So I switched to another approach where I could generate RSA keypair using passphrases. This is one example of this - https://github.com/joekir/deterministics